# Random Variables & Sets

Tags: probability

The number of pumps in use at both a six-pump station and a four-pump station will be determined. Give the possible values for each of the following random variables. (Enter your answers in set notation.)

Z = the number of stations having exactly two pumps in use

Z = ?

I dont understand what "the number of stations having exactly two pumps in use" means. Are they talking about the three cases where 2 pumps total are being used?

Comment: As I understand it, it may be that no station is using one, one station is, or both are using two pumps. Then express that in set notation.

Comment: You have two stations so the number of stations having exactly two pumps in use can be $0$, $1$ or $2$.